# Some ScalaTest suites are not being executed

Tags: scala, scalatest

Given a class following the `ScalaTest` signature:

```
class GEMTests extends FunSuite with Matchers with BeforeAndAfterAll {
```

And inside of it we have some  enabled tests like this:

```
test("GEMFullPostal") {
   // logic, logic, ..
}
```

Why would a certain Test Suite *not* be executed? Other test suites are being run correctly.

When I run the test suite through Intellij it does run that given test - which promptly fails due to an incorrect sql statement. But both

```
  mvn test
```

and the Jenkins CI/CD build allows the entire application to pass scalatest . I can see in the output *no mention* of that particular class.

So .. intellij recognizes the class as a ScalaTest  but it is being skipped by `maven` command line (including jenkins).  What might be "special" about this test suite?    Note it is in the same directory as other Test Suites that *are* being run automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue:  inside the `pom.xml` there is a filtering mechanism happening for the `scalatest` plugin

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <suffixes>(?&lt;!Integration)(Test|Spec)</suffixes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
```

So the fix is to add the `Tests` extensions to that filter:

```
<suffixes>(?&lt;!Integration)(Test|Tests|Spec)</suffixes>
```